# Difference : がいます or います

Tags: meaning

1. 私には あなただけ がいます。
2. 私には あなただけ います。

Hello, can anyone tell me if there is any difference in meaning for the above sentences?  Which one is more natural?

Comment: どちらもあまり自然じゃないと思います。。「私にはあなたしかいません。」のほうがいいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most the cases,

> 私には あなただけ がいます。

would be used. It is the more natural one. The second one would be slightly grammatically incorrect.

The rough definition of both would be "you are the only one to me".

I hope this helps, and please tell me if you would need any clarification!

Comment: Thanks! So both would be accepted by native speakers, right? But why が should be added? What is its function?

Comment: The が is equivalent to something like "are", so the one missing would be something like "You the only one to me" instead of "You are the only one to me". Although like @Chocolate suggested above, 私にはあなたしかいません would work better and sound more natural. I hope this clarifies it!